# Как работать с изометрической картой в браузере на canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Я прочитал, что браузерная версия игры Forge of Empires сейчас переписана на Haxe+OpenFL+canvas:
https://habr.com/ru/post/488814/
Интересно как выводятся и обрабатываются объекты-картинки на изометрической карте.
Думаю, что в браузер выводится статичная картинка, в центре картинки координаты 0:0, от них идет разбиение на клетки в изометрической проекции. Наверно перед отрисовкой мы запрашиваем в базе данных какие объекты находятся у пользователя на карте, и их координаты и выводим их следующим слоем на карте - по нужным координатам так, чтобы передние картинки закрывали дальние. Возможно хорошее решение будет сохранять в базе "картинку-скриншот" состояния города и при следующем входе пользователя не отрисовывать каждый объект, а выдать сохранённый скриншот, а отривку зданий по координатам включать только при переходе в режим строительства или перемещения зданий. 
Вопрос:
1. Возможна ли такая технология с сохраниением "картинки-скриншота" состояния города?
(допустим у нас в базе данных будет столбец хранения скриншота, который будет обновляться при каждой перестройке города)

Потом когда нам нужно построить здание - вопрос:
2. как устроена технология, которая подсвечивает зелёным или красным клетки на карте где мы хотим  построить объект?
(возможно у нас 2 картинки и мы выводим то с зелёной подсветкой, то с красной, либо мы делаем ещё полупрозрачный слой размером с объект и он меняет свойство - цвет с зелёного на красный)

Вопрос 3. Как устроен отлёт монет от зданий при наведении мыши?
(над каждым зданием ведётся отсчёт времени, по наступлении положенного времени объект монеты становится visible, при наведении на объект мыши срабатывает функция анимации отлёта вверх - в базу идёт запрос на прибавление суммы над зданием к сумме денег пользователя)

Вопрос 4: Как устроен вывод окна исследований с деревом с наполнением статус-бара по каждому исследованию: (ну должна же быть библиотека...)

Вопрос 5: Как реализован пошаговый бой на гексогональной карте в проекции?
(должны же быть реализации, или библиотечки....)

Если есть информация, то напишите движки, библиотечки JS, скрипты-аналоги, учебную литературу, учебные статьи, как можно это реализовать. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.